# Java swap lowest number in array with chosen number

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I don't know how to swap the smallest number in an array with a number that I choose. The method I have to use in order to do this is swapNum(). Then after I do that, I have to print out the array, but with the modifications I did from swapNum()

```
public class Data
{
    private int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,};

    private int smallNum = numbers[0];
    private int largeNum = numbers[0];

    private int countNum = 0;

    public void setsmallNum(int smallNum)
    { this.smallNum = smallNum; }

    public void setlargeNum(int largeNum)
    { this.largeNum = largeNum; }

    public void setcountNum(int countNum)
    { this.countNum = countNum; }

    public int getsmallNum()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] < smallNum)
            {
            smallNum = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return smallNum;
    }

    public int getlargeNum()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > largeNum)
            {
                largeNum = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return largeNum;
    }

    public int getcountNum()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] == countNum)
            {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Number is at index: " + i);
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public int swapNum()
    {
    /* swap lowest number in array with a selected number 
       that I choose such as d.setcountNum(5)
    */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Data d = new Data();
        d.getlargeNum();
        d.getsmallNum();
        d.setcountNum(5);
        System.out.println("Largest number: " + d.getlargeNum());
        System.out.println("Smallest number: " + d.getsmallNum());
        System.out.println("Number appears " + d.getcountNum() + " times");
     // System.out.println(Print out the modified array from swapNum() method)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, smallest number is stored in the global `smallNum` variable.

Using this value create a function that takes a number of your choice as an argument. Then find the smallest number in the array and swap using temp variable.

```
public int swapNum(int num){
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) 
         if(numbers[i] == smallNum){ //find smallest value in array.
             temp = numbers[i];
             numbers[i] = num;
         }
     }
     return temp; //You can return the value that was swapped
}
```

Create another function that displays the content of `numbers` array. Call it whenever you want.

```
    public void display(){
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Several modifications can be done to improve code efficiency.

Comment: I pasted these two comments right before the main and got these errors. imgur.com/a/Q9csl

Comment: Can you paste the entire code in the question again?

Comment: I put it at the bottom of my questions.

Comment: There is a opening curly brace missing in swap function. Kindly use proper indentation. Helps for a better code reading.

Comment: My code works and my problem is solved, thank you so much for the help